# Replace a word in files and folders name

Tags: vb.net, file, directory

I would like to find a way to replace one word in another, but the word will be in the file or folder name.
EDIT
Following the advice of @the_lotus I managed to write this code:

```
listf = Directory.GetFiles(paths, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

For Each file As String In listf
    Dim name
    name = Path.GetFileName(file)
    If name.contains("server1") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(file, name.replace("server1", "abcd"))
    End If
Next
listd = Directory.GetDirectories(paths, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
For Each nome As String In listd
    Dim name
    name = New DirectoryInfo(nome).Name
    If name.contains("server1") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(nome, name.replace("server1", "abcd"))
    End If

Next
MsgBox("done")
```

In the renaming of the files no problem, but when the folders are renamed the whole path changes and therefore I get errors when the program tries to rename the remaining folders
EDIT
To settle the matter of the path I was only served in the string that the path of all this: "/wordthatwasreplacedinthenames/" with "/wordthat usedtoreplacethe old/" in this way has changed all the folders with the old word with the new one more as I put the two slash does not change the last folder that is still to be renamed.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the substring is. A `String` is a `String`. What it represents is irrelevant for what you want to do.

Comment: @jmcilhidenney edited

Comment: If you would 'like to find a way' then you can go to google and find the way. If you have a code attempt and a good reason why it isn't working then you should post it

Comment: You need to separate your problem into smaller pieces. Can you read a file. Can you read a folder. Can you rename a file or folder. Can you use a string. Can you replace a word in a string.

Comment: @AFriend I searched on the internet but I only found a code in VBA nothing more.

Comment: If you rename a parent directory, then obviously all the child directories that come later in the list will no longer be valid.  So, you'll need to figure out some other way to do it.  You could handle all the longest directory names first, or you could fix all of the items in the list that are in the same parent, or you could recursively walk through each directory level renaming the parent first and then looping through its sub directories, or you could just reload the full list each time after you rename one, or...

Comment: Not to be mean, but to put it in other words, you have to use a little critical thinking and come up with your own algorithm for how to accomplish the work.  That's what programming is.  This site is for helping people solve the technical problems they are running into while implementing their already devised algorithms and solutions.  The purpose of this site is not to come up with the algorithms for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To settle the matter of the path I was only served in the string that the path of all this: "/wordthatwasreplacedinthenames/" with "/wordthat usedtoreplacethe old/" in this way has changed all the folders with the old word with the new one more as I put the two slash does not change the last folder that is still to be renamed.